# Getting exception Unsupported filter: Contains(value(System.String[])) in FilterDefinition of MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to build filter as below

```
Builders<Documents>.Filter.Where(x => filterJsonObj.HeaderFilterCreatedByList.Contains(EncryptHelper.DecryptText(x.CreatedBy)));
```

but it is throwing error at runtime

> Unsupported filter: Contains(value(System.String[])).

But for below mentioned Filter it is working properly only diff in below filter query is in that I am not using any additional method.

```
Builders<Documents>.Filter.Where(x => filterJsonObj.DocumentTypes.Contains(x.Status));
```

Details of the method which I am using to decrypt is as below

```
public static string DecryptText(string decryptedValue)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(decryptedValue)) return decryptedValue;
            var values = decryptedValue.Split(",");
            var decryptedValues = new List<string>();
            foreach (var v in values)
            {
                decryptedValues.Add(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(v) ? v : EncryptDecrypt(v));
            }
            return String.Join(",", decryptedValues);
        }
```

Comment: Perhaps, query all `Documents` collection from MongoDB as `IEnumerable`/`List`, next using *LINQ* `Where` to filter the data with invoking `EncryptHelper.DecryptText(x.CreatedBy)`?

Comment: What is the return type of `EncryptHelper.DecryptText`?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Return type of the same is String only. Want to use that method to decrypt the value first then to compare the same.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I have updated the question and added code of that method.

Comment: @YongShun Same functionality is working properly in IEnumerable / List. I am already using the same in some another part but I can not use the same here. Because I have to build multiple filter basis on multiple conditions and it also has Array field in that document on which I am doing processing basis on the multiple filters which I am appending.

Answer (score 0):

This one I have handled using below code

```
string[] createdByList = filterJsonObj.HeaderFilterCreatedByList.Select(x => EncryptHelper.EncryptText(x)).ToArray();
fil &= Builders<Documents>.Filter.In(x => x.CreatedBy, createdByList);
```

Instead of using Decryption method in the Filter first I have encrypted the list then used the same in Filter.

Any suggestions in the same are acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason Additional method won't work because I tried to use StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase and it showed error - **Unsupported filter: value(System.String[]).Contains({document}{JobTitle}, value(System.CultureAwareComparer)).**

If you want to refine your list you can do it after applying other filters and then on that filtered list you will be able to use the filter with additional method.

**For Eg:** var listData = filteredList.Where( ArrayOfString.Contains("Value", StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).ToList();
Hope that works for you !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).